# Click event NSTextField OSX

Tags: swift, macos

I am having multiple textfields and I won't to invoke an action method if the user clicks on a textfield, this is what I currently have:

```
override func mouseDown(theEvent: NSEvent) {

}
```

for the click event.

This is the action to which it should reference when a textfield is pressed:

```
func myAction(sender: NSView)
{
    print("aktuell: \(sender)")
    currentObject = sender
}
```

For buttons it is working with the action and selector but this does not work for textfields...

```
button.action = #selector(myAction)
```

Please give examples only in swift, I know that there are plenty of examples in obj.-c. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working with that:

**1)** Create a subclass of NSTextField.

```
import Cocoa

class MyTextField: NSTextField {

    override func mouseDown(theEvent:NSEvent) {
        let viewController:ViewController = ViewController()
        viewController.textFieldClicked()
    }
}
```

**2)** With Interface building, select the text field you want to have a focus on. Navigate to Custom Class on the right pane. Then set the class of the text field to the one you have just created.**

**3)** The following is an example for ViewController.

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override var representedObject: AnyObject? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }

    func textFieldClicked() -> Void {
        print("You've clicked on me!")
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use target action inside of `mouseDown()`. This will call the appropriate method. Creating a new view controller is a very bad idea.